# Flutter Video Player streaming videos error only on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, video

I got this error only when streaming videos using flutter Video Player on iOS device:
flutter: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Operation Stopped, null, null).

Following is my video player cubit code

```
try {
      if (controller != null) {
        controller?.pause();
      }
      controller?.dispose();
      controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(

        Uri.parse(
            'https://vacademy.kportals.net/api/v1/stream/video?mediaId=64b33199e21a3bd3134aa6da'
        ),
        httpHeaders:
        {
          "Authorization":
          "Bearer ${MyApp.navKey.currentState!.context.read<AuthProvider>().loggedInUser!.token}",
          "Range": "bytes=0-"
        },
      );

      controller?.initialize().then((value) {

        chewieController?.dispose();
        chewieController = ChewieController(
          zoomAndPan: true,
          placeholder: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ),
          deviceOrientationsOnEnterFullScreen: [
            DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
            DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
          ],
          videoPlayerController: controller!,
          autoPlay: true,
        );

        emit(VideoInitializedState());


      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
```

I tried changing the video player package, and adjust code in backend, but nothing worked